# Array.map 1 element to multiple element

Tags: javascript, map-function

I have `[3, 16, 120]`. when I do `[3, 16, 120].map(mapper)`, I want to achieve, for example `[4,5,  17,18,  121,122]` i.e. each element map to n+1 and n+2. This is of course an example - what I want is to simply push multiple values from mapper function

Do I have to use Array.each and push to an array, or is it possible to do it with Array.map (or other built-in api)

Comment: You could probably use `Array.reduce`, though I'm not sure it would be any better than using `Array.forEach`.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You can use [`reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) and add to array `e+1, e+2` of each element.

```js
var ar = [3, 16, 120];

var result = ar.reduce(function(r, e) {
  r.push(e+1, e+2);
  return r;
}, []);

console.log(result)
```

This is ES6 version with arrow function

```js
var ar = [3, 16, 120];

var result = ar.reduce((r, e) => r.push(e+1, e+2) && r, []);
console.log(result)
```

PS: Array.push seems to be faster and has no `Maximum call stack..` error, see below:

```
a = Array(1000000).fill(1); st = Date.now(); Array.prototype.concat.apply([], a.map(function (n) { return [n+1, n+2]; })); console.log(`${Date.now() - st}ms `);
> RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

a = Array(1000000).fill(1); st = Date.now(); a.reduce((r, e) => r.push(e+1, e+2) && r, []); console.log(`${Date.now() - st}ms `);
> 180ms
```

So .push is preferable comparing to accepted solution.

Comment: You're modifying `r` in the callback, which means this is just an unnecessarily complicated `for` loop.

Comment: I just added performance test to answer, and it seems to be `.push` is preferable comparing to `.concat` in this case. Also concat will throw `Maximum call stack` exception for big arrays

Comment: check @jabacchetta's answer below https://stackoverflow.com/a/58479956/782114

Answer (score 30):

### 2019 Update

Use [`Array.prototype.flatMap()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap), introduced in ES10.

```
const oddNumbers = [1, 3, 5, 7, 9];
const allNumbers = oddNumbers.flatMap((number) => [number, number + 1]);
console.log(allNumbers); // [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

Answer (score 20):

I come up with one myself, using spread operator.

`[].concat(...[3, 16, 120].map(x => [x+1, x+2]))`

Answer (score 11):

Not particularly nice, but it is a possible solution:

```js
var arr = [3, 16, 120];

console.log([].concat.apply([], arr.map(function (n) { return [n+1, n+2]; })));
```

Comment: you should consider using `Array.prototype.concat` instead of `[].concat`. Its shorter but you are allocating a new array everytime this runs

Comment: @eltonkamami I'm already allocating n+3 arrays anyway. n+4 isn't going to make things much worse.

Answer (score 4):

you could produce an array for each items, then concat all these arrays :

```
[3, 16, 120].map(x => [x+1, x+2] ).reduce( (acc,val) => acc.concat(val), []);
```

Comment: Nice but it does 2 passes of the array and doubled array

Comment: Yes I think @Nenad Vracar solution is better than mine

Answer (score 4):

You could use [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) in combination with [`Array#concat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat).

```js
console.log([3, 16, 120].reduce(function (r, a) {
    return r.concat(a + 1, a + 2);
}, []));
```

ES6

```js
console.log([3, 16, 120].reduce((r, a) => r.concat(a + 1, a + 2), []));
```

Answer (score 3):

Immutable solution, with the spread operator:

```
[3, 16, 120].reduce((a, v) => [...a, v+1, v+2], [])
```

Answer (score 2):

using `Array#concat` and `Array#map`

```
Array.prototype.concat.apply([], [3, 16, 120].map(x => [x+1, x+2] ));
```

Answer (score 2):

Just for fun, an ES6 solution with a generator:

```js
var arr = [3, 16, 120];

var [...result] = (function*() { for( i of arr){ yield ++i; yield ++i; }})();

console.log(result);
```

Comment: I never know this can work... 1. generator can be expanded with spread operator (well, it's iterable) 2. spread operator is slower than assignment Good one!

Answer (score 2):

Using Array.prototype.flat():

```js
const doubled = [3, 16, 120].map(item => [item + 1, item + 2]).flat();

console.log(doubled)
```

Fair warning – not a standard method to this date (posted 12/2018).