# Return multiple values from ES6 map() function

Tags: collections, ecmascript-6, flatmap

Say I have something like this:

```
let values = [1,2,3,4]; 

let newValues = values.map((v) => {
  return v *v ; 
}); 

console.log(newValues); //[1,4,9,16]
```

Pretty straight forward.

Now what if I want to return multiple values for each of my objects?

eg.

```
let values = [1,2,3,4]; 

let newValues = values.map((v) => {
  return [v *v, v*v*v, v+1] ; 
}); 

console.log(newValues); //This is what I want to get 
                        //[1, 1, 2, 4, 8, 3, 9, 27, 4, 16, 64, 5]
```

I can use a reduce function

```
let values = [1,2,3,4]; 

let newValues = values.map((v) => {
  return [v *v, v*v*v,v+1] ;
}).reduce((a, c) => {

  return a.concat(c); 
}); 

console.log(newValues);
```

But is that the best way to do this?

Comment: You are asking for flatmap. See [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39838385/831878)

Comment: @RayToal Thanks. I feel like a lot of effective programming is knowing the correct terminology.

Comment: linked - https://stackoverflow.com/q/38528473/104380

Answer (score 80, accepted):

With using only one `reduce()` you can do this. you don't need `map()`.
better approach is this:

```js
const values = [1,2,3,4];
const newValues= values.reduce((acc, cur) => {
  return acc.concat([cur*cur , cur*cur*cur, cur+1]);
    // or acc.push([cur*cur , cur*cur*cur, cur+1]); return acc;
}, []);

console.log('newValues =', newValues)
```

EDIT:
The better approach is just using a flatMap (as @ori-drori mentioned):

```js
const values = [1,2,3,4]; 

const newValues = values.flatMap((v) => [v *v, v*v*v, v+1]); 

console.log(JSON.stringify(newValues)); //[1, 1, 2, 4, 8, 3, 9, 27, 4, 16, 64, 5]
```

Comment: Why not just use `.push()` rather than create a new array every time through the loop?  You can pass multiple values to  `.push()`.  In fact, you don't really need to use `.reduce()` either.  `for/of` or `.forEach()` will work just fine where you just `.push()` values in to a previously declared array.

Comment: @jfriend00 because `reduce()` is a functional programming method (my priority). and of course your solution works fine too.

Comment: Dislike because  (1) this is very slow - On^2 - and (2) there is a built in fn *flatMap* no need for bad practices ( implementing another function besides the official one )

Answer (score 61):

If you need to map an array, and flatten the results you can use [`Array.flatMap()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap):

```js
const values = [1,2,3,4]; 

const newValues = values.flatMap((v) => [v *v, v*v*v, v+1]); 

console.log(JSON.stringify(newValues)); //[1, 1, 2, 4, 8, 3, 9, 27, 4, 16, 64, 5]
```

If `Array.flatMap()` is not available flatten the results of the map by using [Array#concat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) and the [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator):

```js
const values = [1,2,3,4]; 

const newValues = [].concat(...values.map((v) => [v *v, v*v*v, v+1])); 

console.log(JSON.stringify(newValues)); //[1, 1, 2, 4, 8, 3, 9, 27, 4, 16, 64, 5]
```

Comment: This is beautiful. very clever use of how `concat` works with multiple Array parameters.

Comment: TypeError: flatMap is not a function
i am getting this error in node v10.18.1

Comment: It's not supported in node v10, but there are polyfills, and you can also use the `[].concat()` solution in the answer instead.

Comment: Other alternative would be to use `.map().flat()`

Answer (score 6):

By definition, `.map()` returns an array of the same length as the input array so it's just not a good choice when you want to create a different length result.

From an efficiency point of view, it's probably best to use `for/of` and avoid creating lots of intermediate arrays:

```
let values = [1,2,3,4];

let result = [];
for (let val of values) {
    result.push(val*val , val*val*val, val+1);
}
```

If you wanted to use array methods efficiently, you could use `.reduce()` with `.push()` to avoid creating a new array on every iteration:

```
let values = [1,2,3,4]; 

let result = values.reduce((array, val) => {
    array.push(val*val , val*val*val, val+1);
    return array;
}, []);
```

Answer (score 0):

Better use `flatMap` from [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.5#flatMap)

```
 const output = _.flatMap([1,2,3,4], (v, index, arr) => [v *v, v*v*v, v+1])
```

output: [
   1,
   1,
   2,
   4,
   8,
   3,
   9,
   27,
   4,
   16,
   64,
   5
]